# How do I add the Categories and tags related to each entry?

Tags: templating, entries, categories, tags

This is my basic entry layout and I just want to display the linked category and tag names as indicated…

```
<div class="posts sidemeta">
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').find() %}
<div class="post format-standard">
    <div class="date-wrapper">
        <div class="date">
            <span class="day">{{ entry.postDate | date("d") }}</span>
            <span class="month">{{ entry.postDate | date("M") }}</span>
        </div><!-- /.date -->
    </div><!-- /.date-wrapper -->
    <div class="post-content">
        <h2 class="post-title">
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <ul class="meta">
            <li class="categories">Category: <a href="#">Category Name</a></li>
            <li class="tags">Tags: <a href="#">Tag 1</a>, <a href="#">Tag 2</a>, <a href="#">Tag 3</a></li>
            <li class="share"><a href="#">Share</a></li>
        </ul><!-- /.meta -->
        {{ entry.body.getPage(1) }}
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="btn">Read more</a>
    </div><!-- /.post-content -->
</div><!-- /.post -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your categories and tags fields are named, respectively, `newsCategories` and `newsTags`, you could do the following for the categories:

```
{% for category in entry.newsCategories %}
    <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And for the tags:

```
{% for tag in entry.newsTags %}
    <a href="{{ tag.url }}">{{ tag.title }}</a>
    {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This code is untested, but I think this should more or less do what you want to achieve.